# Oracle DB Link Usages

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

I would like your opinion about usage of dblinks in oracle.Below are the points about my database architecture.

- One centralized database [Database1]
- Inside centralized database i have only 1 schema(central) ,which contains a table X
- One OLTP database [Database2]
- Inside Database2 , i have multiple schemas ,which contain same table X with different volumes of data.
- I have create multiple private database link(non shared) from Database1 central schema to different schema(100 count) in Database2 to fetch data from table X(based on some sync flag) to central table X
- I have written simple procedure that run every 10 seconds in central schema(Database1)  to connect each schema in Database2 to copy X into central X table

Question -

1. I am closing Db links after each connection, but will this lead to any kind of db links issue, if the process does not complete in 10 seconds and another process starts for the refresh?
2. What will be the correct approach to implement this, as there might be other processes which use the DB link for some other purpose.

PS: MAX number of dblink in one session is 32

Comment: Why don’t you create a view in database2 that exposes all the data? You would have access to read this view only from database1 which is way more secure. And you would need only one stable database link and no recreating / closing etc. If I say simpler: gather the data in database2 and then take it to database1

Comment: @smnbbrv: Thanks ,that makes sense ,but creating a view over 100 schema (going to increase)will be a tedious and consume more resources,rather than iterating over each schema.

Comment: Rather than using tables and writing a stored procedure to synchronise them you should use materialized views in the second database and use Oracle's built-in management features. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REPLN/repmview.htm#REPLN003)

Comment: @APC: Thanks , Can you help me with the approach, do I have to create a mv on every 100 schemas? or a single mv over all the schema's?

Comment: One MV per schema

Comment: @APC : And post that we will be creating a single view over all the mv and use dblink to fetch db from db2 to db1? Is my understanding correct?